# Rails Use Form and Bootsratp Date Picker to Store Datetime

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I am using Bootstrap date picker to set the date within the calendar that pops up. However, in the form to simply use the pop-up calendar date picker it must be a text_field as shown:

`<%= f.text_field :start_dt, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>`

The issue with this is that I wish to store it as a datetime, and I received an argument out of bounds error by using the text_field. If I set the fields to `f.datetime_field`, several drop downs appear in the form of Year, Month and Day and does not display the calendar I wanted.

Is there a setting in the rails form_for that allows for setting a datetime without automatically displaying that series of menus for the date select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try parsing the text_field to yield a DateTime object, then store it:

```
>> DateTime.parse("2014-01-01")
=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 +0000
>> Date.parse("2014-01-01")
=> Wed, 01 Jan 2014
```

**EDIT:** You could implement this at the model level as follows - change your param name to :start_dt_string, then parse it into your DateTime object before_save:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :parse_date

  def parse_date
    unless start_dt_string.blank?
      self.start_dt = DateTime.parse(start_dt_string)
    end

    unless end_dt_string.blank?
      self.end_dt = DateTime.parse(end_dt_string)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: With the text_field simply as `<%= f.text_field :start_dt, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>` how/where can I implement your suggestion into this field?

Comment: Implement it on the business end of the form - your controller, or at the model level on a before_save callback.